# Finding shortest regex match in Python

Tags: python, regex

I want to process a string like this `(a (b) c)` and I want to match the inner `(b)` first before processing the outer parens. However, this code doesn't work:

```
>>> x='(a(b)c)'
>>> re.search(r"\((.*?)\)", x).group(1)
'a(b'
```

Is there any way to ask Python to find a minimal match (ie, `b`) rather than the longer match `a(b`?

Answer (score 3):

XY problem. You can't process the minimal match. What you can do is find a match without parentheses.

```
r"\(([^()]*)\)"
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: "I want to process the inner (b) first before **removing it** and processing the outer parens" (emphasis mine). Once you replace the inner expression with a non-parenthesised expression, you can find the outer one. This would typically be done in a loop; no way to do it with one regexp execution.

Comment: This solves my issue Amadan.  Thanks.  Side question: what does "minimal" mean in python regex's if not "match as few characters as possible"?

Comment: Exactly that - but at the place where you're matching, For example, `a.+z` matched against `abcz adz` would match `abcz adz` - The first `a` available, then as much other characters as possible, then `z`. Only if the first `a` couldn't be worked into the match would the second `a` be tested, like with `ad+z`. In contrast, `a.+?z` will match `abcz` - the first `a`, as little other characters possible ("minimal"), then `z`. It will *not* match `adz`, because another viable match is available sooner.

Comment: Perhaps python docs should call it "earliest minimal" or "leftmost minimal" instead of just "minimal" then.  I was quite misled by the term "minimal", thinking it meant "smallest possible"

Comment: Could you not just use `"(\(.*?)(\(.*?\))(.*?\))"` ? So that `group(1)` is the middle parameter, and concatenating `group(0)` and `group(2)` would get you the entire string without the middle section? Or am I not seeing the problem here?

Comment: @Fixee: It is clear to people who know how regular expressions work (i.e. trying the match at each position, each operator only operates locally). Python docs writers apparently did not feel the need to explain the concept of regular expressions and particulars of its evaluation, just like they don't explain what a process is in multiprocessing docs. (FWIW, I don't think Python docs are ideal, but in this case I can't really blame them.)

Comment: @Alastor: I imagine the problem is not restricted to the exact case in the question. My answer shows how you can evaluate `(2+((3*5)-(7*4)))`: by recursive substitution of inner parentheses. Yours can't.